# Argument 1 passed to PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime() must be an instance of PHPExcel_Cell, double given

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel for my code and I'm getting an error in this part:

line 159 -179 :

```
if($extitle == $h){ 

                    $data = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);


                            if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($data)){
                                    $cellValue = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
                                    $dateValue = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cellValue);

                                     $dob =  date('Y-m-d',$dateValue);                              

                                        $tz  = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila');
                                        $rage = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dob, $tz)->diff(new DateTime('now', $tz))->y;

                            }else{

                                $dob = "NULL";

                            }

                }
```

line 180 -185

```
if($extitle == $i){ $data = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();   $mstatus = $data;               
                }

                if($extitle == $j){ $data = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();   $category = $data;              
                }
```

I get the error : `Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime() must be an instance of PHPExcel_Cell, double given, called in *****\uploadexceldata.php on line 187 and defined in ******\Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\Date.php on line 254`

```
if($extitle == $q){

                    $data = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();           

//in this part the error occured    



                    if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($data)){
                                    $cellValue = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
                                    $dateValue = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cellValue);

                                     $efdate =  date('Y-m-d',$dateValue);                               



                            }else{

                                $efdate = "NULL";

                            }
                }
```

But, when I erase the line 189 where `if($extitle == $p){   $data = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();` it works fine.

Now, I want to know why this happens and how do I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)
```

returns a PHPExcel_Cell object

```
$data = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
```

does not return a PHPExcel_Cell object, simply a scalar value such as a number or string

As the `isDateTime()` method requires a PHPExcel_Cell object as its arguments, `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($data)` will give this error when `$data` is a scalar

Either use the same logic that you're using in lines 159-> to get `$data` as a PHPExcel_Cell object, and use a subsequent call to

```
$cellValue = $data->getValue();
```

or something like

```
$data = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();           
    if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row))){
```

Comment: Thanks Sir you always save me when im in trouble